# Отправили в административную ссылку в Воронеж. Правилен ли падеж у соседних обстоятельств?

Tags: синтаксис, падежи, обстоятельство

Могут ли два обстоятельства места, которые стоят рядом, выражаться существительными в одинаковых падежах? Или в данном случае это одно обстоятельство?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отправили в административную ссылку в Воронеж.

Можно считать, что это **одно обстоятельство** с двумя определениями ― согласованным и обстоятельственным несогласованным.

Можно считать, что это **неоднородные обстоятельства**, которые обозначают цель и место.